Why isolation resistor on a serial port between MCU and transceiver?
Circuit I've inherited:

Mostly a run of the mill RS485 transceiver. On the right the bus, on the left an STM32.
The 10R are probably some attempt to limit the fault current when the TVS is not enough? IMHO if it get past the TVS it's not a current issue but more a voltage surge (letting aside the fact that the MAX480 is 15kV ESD protected, maybe it's a more serious transient like EFT). The absolute maximum is 12.5V so I doubt than 10R would be enough to save it (nominal input impedance is 12kR).
Other function? I don't thing it's a filter thing since there is no explicit capacitance (you get maybe 10-20pF of parasitics)
On the MCU side I think that the 1k are not for fault resilience (since there isn't one on DE) neither for generic noise suppression (same). The only thing I could think of is smoothing down edge transients, maybe? I'd have seen ferrites for that but never resistor. The rest of the circuit also has no sensitive parts (it's an I/O board running from 24V lines so I guess the transceiver noise is the least around there)
Any other ideas of why they put these (seemingly) useless resistors?

It's either an error or just poor design. To answer the question, one would need to know if those specific pins on that specific STM32 are 5V tolerant or not. The difference is between resistors being useless or highly important to keep the STM32 from damaging. Also relates to how 5V supply for MAX485 and the unknown STM32 supply voltage relate to each other at startup and shutdown. I mean, the STM32 cannot be powered from same 5V as the MAX485, unless via regulator. Also depends on if those TX and RX wires go anywhere else, like an external programming header. Please add more details.

Looking at the data sheet, none of those things seem to be 'required', but the thing with hardware design is it's easier to just chuck in these extra parts and then replace them with 0R links if you don't need them. The time/cost savings are negligible vs having to re-spin a board after finding an EMC problem.

@Jon It depends on the MCU pin. If you put a 0R there, the MCU could blow up.

Right, that transceiver is 5V, but most of the STM32 ports are fault tolerant. Maybe it was copied from another application where it was needed (and anyway it's bad practice due to current injection into the MCU diodes)

The lines are point to point and the MCU is powered from an LDO under the same 5V line so I'd say the supplies go up more or less at the same time. However in the past I always used transceivers designed for 3.3 logic so probably that was the idea; maybe this trick is hidden in some MAX application note. Also: https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-products/rs485-interfacing-with-stm32f030/td-p/341127 ST explicitly recommends translator (and the datasheet warns about injection)

None of the resistors make much sense IMO. They are unlikely to cause any harm but unlikely to do any good either. Pull resistors on the data lines are common practice though, to keep the lines stable when the MCU is rebooting or in case the MCU lacks internal pull resistors.

"letting aside the fact that the MAX480 is 15kV ESD protected" What part are you using, more precisely? 480? 485? With or without E in the end? These part numbers are quite evil; leave out the E and you get some 1980s crap without ESD protection etc.

@Lundin The resistors do make sense depending on perspective you want. And they are not pull resistors, they are in series.

@Justme I didn't say they were pull resistors, I said that pull resistors would have made more sense. As for slew rate control, picking a transceiver which isn't from the 1980s would be a start.

(That being said I very recently did a project where we too used MAX485 and fiddled around with manual slew rate. But that was by using a pi common mode filter for lower baudrates and extreme EMI environments. So it all depends on what the product is for.)

Intersil recommend the 10Rresistors for some of their products. It limits the fault current in the case of a transient. I’ve had good success with MAX485 with the series 10 Ohm resistors along with larger transzorbs. My application was1km runs in high lightning prone areas. A nearby lightning strike would cause the electronics to reboot but rarely did a MAX485 or transzorbs fail.

What are your data rate, cable lengths, expected BER?

Also what is the cable impedance and terminator value?

I found the 10 ohm resistors in a TI appnote with their transceiver but it was in conjunction with filter capacitor (the classic filter configuration). Probably it helps with transients to. At this point I guess the original designer used the recommended techniques for another transceiver on this one

Here is an initial answer which I can improve if more details are given, but the basic reasons are here.
For the RS-485 bus side seemingly non-useful 10R series resistors, while they might not be necessary, the fact is that MAX485 does not have slew rate limited bus drivers, so if the full 2.5 MBPS data rate is not needed or slew causes EMI or signal integrity issues such as ringing on the bus, the resistors limit the slew rate by limiting the current driven to charge the bus capacitance. It thus makes sense to put series resistors there in the schematics, and determine later if they need to be adjusted or replaced by 0R links if the bus needs stronger drive.
For the MCU side resistors, there could be multiple reasons.
First reason is that MAX485 must have a 5V supply and the MCU must have about 3.3V supply.
The MAX485 DI input is compatible with 3.3V logic levels from MCU output so that should not require any resistor like there is none on the RE/DE. For slew rate,  impedance control, and ringing control, you could use a few ten ohms, but 1k would be a value that is seemingly just too high for normal operation. Maybe the 1k is a placeholder for an actual value. But like many other MCUs, the STM32 has programmable drive strength to control the slew rate.
The MAX485 DO is a 5V logic level output. The STM32 has pins that are 5V tolerant and pins that are not 5V tolerant.
The 1k could make sense with a 3.3V tolerant pin, because it will act as a crude level shifter and clamping current would be t a relatively safe but high level, but it's required for the high data rate. Resistance can't be much lower or the clamping current will be too high.
If the STM32 pin is 5V tolerant, such a resistor is not necessary, and it would be quite high for slew rate control, and few tens of ohms would be more suitable for MAX485 DO. However the 5V tolerant pins do not tolerate 5V when MCU is unpowered, and there is no clamp diodes so about 4V max should be OK for MCU. This is only OK of MCU supply comes up before 5V and if 5V decays before MCU supply. Which should be OK if the 3.3V is made from the 5V.
The resistors may be there also if they are on a programming UART so you can override the MAX485 always with e.g. TTL UART cable to PC for firmware upload.
Maybe someone just copied over Arduino without thinking as some Arduinos commonly have 1k series resistors on the UART pins to USB UART chip.

+1 on EMI. That would be my first guess too.

This is a proper design solution for a standard CMOS driver with a lower impedance than the cable where the risetime is expected to be less than the delay time. Thus transmission line effects will cause ringing which reduces the margin to threshold which reduces the external noise, and margin which accelerates the bit error rate (BER).  However, I would not expect this to be necessary with the MAX485 chip.
But, what if the MAX481 is being used for many designs fast and slow. If you can change the slew rate with a series R to improve EMI or SNR, towards a closer-matched source impedance to the cable, why not consider it for the application and your design error margin specs.
Examine Zo by taking the ratio for Vol/Io (min, typ or max). If no min. normally that's good but for T-lines that's worse. So adding 10 or 12 Ohms raises the minimum Zout to improve on ringing. It doesn't have to match perfectly to improve significantly on SNR of the analog signals without the 50% loss associated with matched impedance.
My rule of thumb is nominally 50 Ohms for 5.5V logic and 33 Ohms for 3.6V logic but choose the lowest with a tolerance estimate and consider cold temperatures will lower this and too much R will reduce slew rate.
Let's assume the R is there for a good reason.
Consider;

Reflections, maybe
SNR, maybe
EMI reduction , probably
3a. Egress in the AM or SW band
3b. Ingress from power line transients ( lightning )  limited by TVS and 10 Ohms.

The real application must have a Bit rate, path length & impedance to simulate properly together with driver Cout and receiver Cin. EMI test results should be on record.
The output capacitance is small but if the cable length is short and say 70 pF/m then the mismatch is not attenuated as much as a long cable. Also if the load is not terminated to match the cable then ringing reflections may occur at the source when the delay time is more than the risetime.  The Rs = 10 softens this somewhat as both an LPF and raises the low ESR Cout from the bipolar 90 mA drivers. Although this is not specified, so beware of sources of ringing from mismatches and attenuation at both ends.

Source: p.11 https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX1487-MAX491.pdf
Without full details on the context of this schematic resistor, I would not jump to conclusions and see who approved the design.
My Spectral Analysis with a switch may be changed to suit your specs.
rev A
Bit rate 1MBps test with guestimated T-line impedances you can adjust to suit your design.

Conclusion
I agree with those who suggested current limiting with the TVS clamp from line or lightning transients so keep the 10R in is what I recommend.
If you can imagine it, you can simulate it.
e.g. Missing cable end termination.


1kΩ between the CPU and the transceiver is good isolation from noise conducted from the CPU. It also keeps the edge rates to where they need to be for functionality, without excess. Modern MCUs can have very fast output edges - often <10ns risetime. That is entirely excessive to drive a slow RS485 transceiver and an unnecessary path for EMI to sneak through.
The 10Ω resistors are there probably in attempt to limit the short circuit and transient current. This would need to be verified while looking at the MAX485 datasheet or on the bench. They may just happen to limit the die temperature rise to an acceptable value when the output is shorted - if the current is sources from the 5V supply.
If there's any magnetic induction from external sources into the relatively low impedance line, the induced voltages may be quite a bit higher than 5V differential. It is then that the 10Ω resistors come into play, limiting the transient current through the chip's bond wires and ESD diodes from whatever peak voltage is across the TVS.
Filtering-wise, as a rule of thumb, data cables have about 1-10pF/m capacitance, so a 10Ω source resistor won't do much even for quite long cables. Say CAT3 cable is 0.3nF and 1Ω per each 100m. Compare to 10Ω source resistance. So we're dealing with low-pass time constants on the order of 1-10ns for reasonable cable lengths. It will reduce the highest harmonics of any edges or other junk that leaks out of the device. Since cables radiate (and absorb!) more the longer they are, usually, it may have some benefit.
If I was designing this thing, the resistors would be there also for troubleshooting/serviceability. They are built-in current sensors. Hook up a differential probe and you get nice 10mV/mA signal. It will let you easily diagnose a shorted TVS or a shorted receiver, with no need to disconnect anything (!).
I have put many such transducers (since that's what they are!) in various designs and sometimes they can save quite a bit of head-scratching, or at least confirm that I'm not going insane during a troubleshooting session :)

Using over-large source termination resistors can improve EMI over dubious routes (long, crossing between GND planes / gaps, around edges of the board, etc.), and affords some filtering -- though chattering, runt pulses, etc. are unlikely to arise from an MCU or interface IC respectively, so that doesn't seem important here.
Note also, the higher impedance does make the trace more sensitive to ambient EMI (E-field), so this isn't a universal solution.
Source termination resistors won't necessarily be placed on the schematic by the respective transmitter pin (should, but not strictly necessary, schematic ultimately just represents a netlist), but will be placed nearby on the PCB.
A resistor placed near a receiver/input pin has little effect, only against the pin capacitance.  Whereas at the transmitter side, it acts against trace impedance/capacitance as well.
Since you don't show the rest of the schematic(s), and the nets are named, it could well be that they are shared by other pins/devices/peripherals you haven't noticed yet, and resistors might be used to reduce drive strength (resolving accidental bus conflicts that might otherwise damage pin drivers when multiple are active at once).
Regarding the ESD diode and 10R's, the TVS has some maximum clamping voltage, which may still exceed the protectee's ratings.  The resistor limits the resulting current flow.  Consider the case for two TVS diodes in parallel, versus one getting a direct strike and separated by resistor from the next:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Reducing ESD current into the device, even if it's rated adequately (8/15kV say), helps increase robustness while (hopefully) reducing severity of the event: note that ESD may cause latchup when powered, or longer-duration blanking or corruption of data (metastable condition, or bias network or startup time constants, thermal time constants, etc.), so it can improve a class C failure criterion (requires power cycle) to a B (momentary degradation) or A (no degradation) condition.
The downside is the reduction in range due to the resistors increasing driver output resistance.  For shorter length, lower baud, and few nodes, this is fine.
